# Swap values and indexes of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, swap

I have a `std::vector<int>` with contiguous shuffled values from 0 to N and want to swap, as efficiently as possible, each value with its position in the vector.

Example:

```
v[6] = 3;
```

becomes

```
v[3] = 6;
```

This is a simple problem, but I do not know how to handle it in order to make it trivial and, above all, very fast. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: What happens if the vector has only 10 items, and the first item has the value of 1,000?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in-place. What if you have

`v[] = {2, 2, 2, 2}`? What should `v` look like after your transformation?

Comment: create a new vector, fill it, then copy into the old one

Comment: @rlbond: The OP edited his post, adding that those are " contiguous shuffled values from 0 to N"

Comment: I have edited my question. The values range contiguously from 0 to N and are then shuffled. Then there is a one-to-one correspondance between the indexes and the values.

Comment: This isn't trivial. Consider v[1]=2, V[2] = 3, and V[3] = 1. Which is swapped first?

Comment: I don't suppose `N` is known at compile time?

Comment: The reason you can't find a trivial solution is that it's not a trivial problem. It seems like it should be, but it isn't.

Comment: @melak47: N is known at compile time. I use a vector as an example, but it could have been an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `N` at compile time and given the array contains each index in `[0,N)` exactly once, 
it's relatively straight forward (as long as it doesn't have to be in-place, as mentioned in the comments above) :

Construct a new array so that `v'[n] = find_index(v, n)` and assign it to the old one.

Here I used variadic templates with `std::index_sequence` to roll it into a single assignment:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t find_index(const std::array<T,N>& arr, std::size_t index) {
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(std::distance(arr.begin(), std::find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), index)));
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Index>
void swap_index_value(std::array<T,N>& arr, std::index_sequence<Index...> seq){
    arr = { find_index(arr, Index)... };
}

template<typename Integer, std::size_t N>
void swap_index_value(std::array<Integer,N>& arr) {
    swap_index_value(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

The complexity of this is does not look great though. Calling `find_index(arr, n)` for each n in `[0,N)`
will take N * (N+1) / 2 comparisons total (`std::sort` would only take N * log(N)).

However, since we know each index is present in the array, we could just fill out an array of indices
as we walk over the original array, and assuming T is an integral type we can skip some std::size_t <-> T conversions, too:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void swap_index_value(std::array<T,N>& arr){
    std::array<T, N> indices;
    for (T i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        indices[arr[i]] = i;

    arr = indices;
}
```

We're still using twice the space and doing some randomly ordered writes to our array,
but essentially we're down to 2*N assignments, and the code is simpler than before.

Alternatively, we could also `std::sort` if we keep a copy to do lookups in:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void swap_index_value(std::array<T,N>& arr){
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [copy = arr](const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
        return copy[lhs] < copy[rhs];
    });
}
```

First version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4df95cba6bc17db6),
second version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc6edbc547e9e26a),
std::sort version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/412dca827b2c9032)

Benchmarking which one is faster is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: Impressive (and useful)! Thank you!

Comment: @GuillaumeLethuillier actually, all that indexing and indirection was pointless, turns out the result is simply the indices of the values in original order. I've edited the code.