# How to swap std::vector<int> index to data and data to index

Tags: c++, vector, stl, swap

Index : 0 1 2 3
Data : 3 0 1 2

That means `vector[0]` is 3, and `vector[3]` is 2.

Now swap the elements like this.

Output vector:

Index : 0 1 2 3
Data : 1 2 3 0

That means

- '0'  is present in input vector at index '1' , so replace `vector[0]` as '1'
- '3'  is present in input vector at index '0', so replace `vector[3]` as '0'

Can we do this without using temporary variables?

Comment: Do you want to create a new vector or do it in-place?

Comment: In fact, it's [Permutation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group), and in-place operation is a little more complex than return a new vector.

Comment: Yes, doing it in-place is a bit more complicated and would probably require some temporary variables.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this assignment yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap values and indexes of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896226/swap-values-and-indexes-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to create a new vector, then, assuming your vector simply holds a permutation (that way we can avoid checking if our index will go out of range, because it should not), you could construct a function

```
std::vector<int> exchange(const std::vector<int>& in) {
    std::vector<int> out(in.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) out[in[i]] = i;
    return out;
}
```